# How to catch error if the user pulls out the PPC from the cradle?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I have C# windows mobile program.

if the user pull out the PPC in the middle of transfer file from PC to PPC

How I can catch this error ?

thank's

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it: [Testing for and Responding to Network Connections in the .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446548.aspx).

Using the class presented in that article is as easy as:

```
        // Create the network connected watcher
        _network = new Network(false, 5);
        _network.NetworkConnected += OnConnectedEventHandler;
        _network.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

The other option is to use the [OpenNETCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx) Smart Device Framework's `OpenNETCF.WindowsCE.DeviceManagement` class